# IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Tags: machine-learning, index-error

I'm facing problem while extracting  the data from a given file...

```
def main():  
    with open('heart_data_norm.txt', 'r') as f:   
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')  
        next(reader, None)  # skip header  
        rows = np.array([r for r in reader])  
        random.shuffle(rows)  # randomly shuffle the data 

    Y=rows[:,13]
    X=rows[:,1:13]
    X = X.astype(np.float32)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hey, check the shape of X and Y, lets see what it is

Comment: @pluto i have the same problem....any suggestion

Comment: @fatih... im new to this and checked x and y                                                              
 x=[[0.27330148 0.5427986  0.01766839 ... 0.01021079 0.00468571 0.02041552]
 [0.35131446 0.27780625 0.01179921 ... 0.00461791 0.00394874 0.00644693]
 [0.52150905 0.3439262  0.01256359 ... 0.00401493 0.00283624 0.01265716]
 y = [[2.6820000e+03 7.6200000e+02 2.1551581e-02 ... 4.1018486e+00
  4.0691099e+00 6.8241172e+00]
 [3.5850000e+03 7.4200000e+02 1.8158896e-02 ... 5.9719038e+00
  5.0199499e+00 4.5945249e+00]

Comment: Your error message is saying that the array rows has only one column, axis 1 means column and size 1 means its length. Give it another check

Comment: tq @fatih..problem solved